# Understanding javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I can't understand this code. Before entering into the body:

[image: html-javascript]

---

I cant upload text with English. I definitely see array declaration `myArray = new Array();` but suddenly I see `myArray[i]= new array();`. Another I see `myArray[i][j]`

What's happening?

i know that

if i want using method array

i can use myArray = new array(5);

AND

i know that "my Array " = new array();

" " this part just function only name

not using another function

but this code means  'you are wrong'

i need that this part need understanding

PS. thanks for editing and answering:)

i see those

so i need to edit

and i want see former writing

Comment: @chris ツ be nice, you were once a beginner.

Comment: Youre right, but the Headline is too good. Upvoted!

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 4):

`myArray` is an array of arrays. Each `i` element  of `myArray[i]` is an array itself. You can picture it as a 2-d grid, like a cheessboard (8x8 squares):

```
myArray[0][0]   myArray[0][1]   ...   myArray[0][7]

myArray[1][0]   myArray[1][1]   ...   myArray[1][7]

.                                     .
.                                     .
.                                     .

myArray[7][0]   myArray[7][1]   ...   myArray[7][7]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is building an HTML table using a two-dimensional array.

`myArray = new Array();` creates the first array.  In the `while` loop, you are building the first dimension of the array when setting a value to `myArray[i]`.  By calling `myArray[i] = new array();`, you are making that value another array.

The first while loop is going to create as many rows of those 5 values in `titleArray` as long as you keep confirming.  The second of code after that is building an HTML table with a default 1st  followed by as many  as you confirmed in the first loop, and each  will be composed of 5 .

Hope this helps!